# How get element from 2d array and use them for function parameter in c?

Tags: c, arrays, parameters, 2d, text-files

I got 2d array from text file and succeeded to print it. However I can't use those elements for the function parameter.

here is code for printing 2d array:

```
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &row);
    //printf("%d\n", row);
    array = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*row);

    for (u = 0; u < row; u++) {
        array[u] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*col);
        for (v = 0; v < col; v++) {
            fscanf(fp,  "%d", &array[u][v]);
            printf(" %d ", array[u][v]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(*array);
    free(array);
```

and the code for function

```
for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {

        printf("Iteration GCD = %d \n", iteration(u,v));
        printf("Recursive GCD = %d \n", recursive(u,v));

}
```

[image]

and I got the same value... even though each column value is different.
What should I change for my code source?

[entire code]

```
int iteration(int x, int y);
int recursive(int x, int y);


int main(void)
{

    /*Define Variables*/

    LARGE_INTEGER timefeq, start, end;
    int i, u, v, row;
    int col = 2;
    double result;
    int **array;


    FILE *fp = fopen("data1.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("READ ERROR!!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    else {

        fscanf(fp, "%d", &row);
        //printf("%d\n", row);

        array = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*row);

        for (u = 0; u < row; u++) {
            array[u] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*col);
            for (v = 0; v < col; v++) {
                fscanf(fp,  "%d", &array[u][v]);
                printf(" %d ", array[u][v]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        free(*array);
        free(array);
    }

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&timefeq);

    result = pow(2,63);

    if ((u > result - 1) || (v > result - 1)) {
        printf("Wrong input value!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* Compute */
    //array[u][0] = abs(u);
    //array[0][v] = abs(v);

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {

        QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
        iteration(u, v);
        printf("Iteration GCD = %d \n", iteration(u, v));
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);

        printf("Operation time: %.4f μsec\n", 1000 * (double)(end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / (double)timefeq.QuadPart);


        QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
        recursive(u, v);
        printf("Recursive GCD = %d \n", recursive(u,v));
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);

        printf("Operation time: %.4f μsec\n", 1000 * (double)(end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / (double)timefeq.QuadPart);
        printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }

        /*End Program*/
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;


}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/
int iteration(int a, int b) {

    int tmp;

    while (b) {
        tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp%b;
    }
    return a;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------*/
int recursive(int a, int b) {

    if (a%b == 0)
        return b;
    else return recursive(b, a%b);
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: Can you post the entire code? Specifically where exactly the call to the function placed. If it is after the loops u and v won't be changing.

Comment: Unrelated, your reader-code for dynamic creation of your pointer array and each row within is leaking memory. Count the `malloc`s. There are `row+1` total allocations, and only *two* `free`s.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I added the entire source code

Comment: I don't see the line `printf("Iteration GCD = %d \n", iteration(u,v));` anywhere is the "entire code"

Comment: You never pass the values read into the `array` construct made earlier (which is prematurely freed anyway) into either of your functions `iterate` or `recursive`.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I tried to figure out what is the problem and thought just put free for relocating. By the way, although I delete free , I still have same output..!

Comment: @WhozCraig  I tried to figure out what is the problem and thought just put free for relocating. By the way, although I delete free , I still have same output..!

Comment: Can you just show us the lines where you are calling `iterate` or `recursive` ?

Comment: Again, **you never pass the values you read into your `array[][]` to your `iterate` or `recursive` functions.** You go through reading the values, allocating the array and its rows, then free only *first* row and the array of pointers (leaking all the other rows), then plow through your `iterate` and `recursive` loops without ever doing anything with the values you just read.

Comment: If that is the "entire code" then your problem might be the missing library header files `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: There is no 2D array. `int **` is not and cannot point ot a 2D array. A pointer is not an array!

Comment: I realize you were explicitly asked for the entire code, but in the future, please don't post _all_ of it. Instead, create a [mcve] and post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never pass the values read during your load loops into the actual function calls. As it turns out, this is what is *likely* keeping your program from crashing, as you premature free the base pointer array `array` and only the first allocated row immediately after the loader loops. So not only is the `array` no longer valid to access, you also leak `row-1` allocations (all but the first one).

Later on, you do this in several places:

```
iteration(u,v);
```

and

```
recursive(u,v);
```

Those calculations are pointless. `u` and `v` hold the row and column *counts*; they don't hold any of the actual row *values* you read.

Stripping away all the Windows performance counter cruft, the pointless invoke to `pow()`, and properly relocating the memory `free` calls, your code should look more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int iteration(int a, int b) {

    int tmp;

    while (b) {
        tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp%b;
    }
    return a;
}

int recursive(int a, int b) {

    if (a%b == 0)
        return b;
    else return recursive(b, a%b);
}

int main(void)
{
    int u, v, row;
    int col = 2;
    int **array;

    FILE *fp = fopen("data1.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("data1.txt");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &row);
    array = calloc(row, sizeof *array);
    for (u = 0; u < row; ++u)
    {
        array[u] = calloc(col, sizeof **array);
        for (v = 0; v < col; v++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", array[u]+v);
            printf("%d ", array[u][v]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);

    // look at the values passed to iteration and recursive below
    for (u = 0; u < row; ++u)
    {
        printf("Iteration GCD = %d \n", iteration(array[u][0],array[u][1]));
        printf("Recursive GCD = %d \n", recursive(array[u][0],array[u][1]));
        free(array[u]);
    }
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

**Alternative**

The array usage in this code is ultimately pointless itself. All you seem to really want to do is:

- Read a row count
- For each row

  - Read *two* values
  - For those two values, calculate the GCD using two different mechanisms. The time-measurement can still be done, but carefully so as not to involve any actual io operations.
  - Report the results of those calculations

Unless this is for some academic exercise, I see no reason to use any arrays in this *at all*, reducing `main()` into something like:

```
int main()
{
    int row;

    FILE *fp = fopen("data1.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("data1.txt");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &row) == 1 && row > 0)
    {
        while (row--)
        {
            int a,b;
            if (fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &a, &b) == 2)
            {
                printf("Iteration GCD(%d,%d) = %d\n", a,b,iteration(a,b));
                printf("Recursive GCD(%d,%d) = %d\n", a,b,recursive(a,b));
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Ultimately how you do it is up to you and whatever requirements are dictated. But if you don't *have* to make it complicated, then don't.

Comment: I understand what was wrong with my code! thank you